# Debugging issue with PhpStorm and Xdebug

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm, xdebug, symfony4

I'm trying to debug a Symfony 4 project in PhpStorm v2019.1.2 with Xdebug.
The question is, every time I start the debugging session, it will break (without a breakpoint) in `bin/console.php (line 9)`:

```
if (false === in_array(\PHP_SAPI, ['cli', 'phpdbg', 'embed'], true)) {
    echo 'Warning: The console should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the '.\PHP_SAPI.' SAPI'.\PHP_EOL;
}
```

then in `vendor/symfony/web-server-bundle/Resources/router.php (line 25)`:

```
if (ini_get('auto_prepend_file') && !in_array(realpath(ini_get('auto_prepend_file')), get_included_files(), true)) {
    require ini_get('auto_prepend_file');
}
```

before actually entering my code and hitting the breakpoints I set.

How can I fix/prevent this behavior?

This is my PHP version:

> PHP 7.3.1 (cli) (built: Jan  9 2019 22:22:34) ( NTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
>
> Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
>
> Zend Engine v3.3.1, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
>
> with Xdebug v2.7.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans

And this is my `php.ini` xdebug section:

```
[XDEBUG]
zend_extension = "C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.3\ext\php_xdebug-2.7.2-7.3-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 3600
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_log=path_to_log/xdebug.log
xdebug.scream = 0
```

Comment: By break did you mean that debugger stops at that line or it crashes there?

Comment: It stops, as if I had set a breakpoint, which I  didn't.

Comment: Collect and check your xdebug log -- it should tell more about possible reasons (maybe some "ghost breakpoints"...). Also check your actual Xdebug settings (see `phpinfo()` output -- they may differ/loaded from another config file etc). I do not see any obvious reasons why debugger should be stopping there.

Comment: Do you have the path mapping well configured? Is the option `Force break at first line when no path mapping specified` checked? Or is the option `Force break at first line when a script is outside the project` checked?

Comment: The problem, it seems, was the option `Break at first line in PHP scripts` being set in PHPStorm Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Debug, for when I disabled this, the problem stopped. Only now it's printing repeatedly this message on Event Log:
*Debug session was finished without being paused
It may be caused by path mappings misconfiguration or not synchronized local and remote projects.
To figure out the problem check path mappings configuration for '127.0.0.1' server at PHP|Servers or enable Break at first line in PHP scripts option (from Run menu).*

Comment: *"Only now it's printing repeatedly this message on Event Log"* This happens because you are listening for debug connections and have multiple requests to your code (e.g. Ajax calls / 404 requests) that when executed do not stop at any breakpoint. You may disable those notifications if you do not like them.